# ForkJoinPool and Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, forkjoinpool, kotlin-coroutines

As I understand it, by default, if you start a Kotlin Coroutine via `launch` or `async` it'll launch in `CommonPool` (or if you use `GlobalScope`). And `CommonPool` is a `ForkJoinPool` and that, by default, is in non-async mode so it executes tasks in LIFO order. That seems like a very bad choice for something like asynchronous web server applications where we'd want fair scheduling: we don't want the poor sucker who hit our web server first to wait for all calls that came later.

However, Kotlin coroutines add an additional wrinkle here in that there's some bit of code from the Kotlin standard library that will arrange to have those coroutines executed (some variation of the standard asyc select/epoll loop as I understand it). So maybe the LIFO thing isn't a concern?

I could certainly run some experiments and/or step into the code in a debugger to see how this works but I suspect other's have the same question and I bet somebody "just knows" the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/commonpool-default-for-coroutines/11965) on Kotlin Discuss CommonPool is no longer the default and they now default to a "mostly fair" scheduler. Details in the linked discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a concern, because `ForkJoinPool` is not really LIFO.

That is, it's LIFO for a single thread in the pool, but that's where things become interesting with "work stealing part". Task queue for each thread is double linked. So, what is LIFO for one thread is FIFO for another thread that became free.

In general, ForkJoinPool is a great solution for small tasks, and usually your coroutines are considered small, if you use suspending functions wisely.

Also, you can read more about `asyncMode` in documentation, as it's not that "async": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

> asyncMode - if true, establishes local first-in-first-out scheduling
>   mode for forked tasks that are never joined. This mode may be more
>   appropriate than default locally stack-based mode in applications in
>   which worker threads only process event-style asynchronous tasks. For
>   default value, use false.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Work stealing helps if the server is under low load. For the sake of simplicity say we have only a single CPU/core/hyper-thread. Request 1 comes in and needs a DB lookup so we do that in a suspend function. Then request 2 comes in and also needs a DB lookup, then request 3, etc. Assuming all lookups take the same amount of time db lookup for 1 finished before 2, before 3, etc. but if I was busy handling a new request while several DB results finished I could end up handle the DB results in *reverse* order, first helping user 3, then 2, then 1 which seem wrong.

Comment: "This mode may be more appropriate than default locally stack-based mode in applications in which worker threads only process event-style asynchronous tasks" - isn't that exactly the case here? That is, isn't it telling me *not* to use the defaults?

Comment: "Work stealing helps if the server is under low load" - this is simply incorrect. Workstealing helps when you have many small tasks. In case of Kotlin, every block between two suspending functions is considered a task. You're correct that coroutines may finish in different order than they were originally submitted. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: If I understanding correctly, work stealing helps when you have many small tasks **and** there's a free thread to steal work. But if all threads stay busy they won't steal work - they'll each continue to work on their own queues in LIFO order, right? For simplicity say I have 1 thread in CommonPool (1 CPU) and I never suspend. I have an HTTP server that enqueues each HTTP request as a coroutine. So request 1 comes in and I start working on it. While I'm doing that requests 2 - 100 come in. When I'm done with 1 I'll pick the next task from the ForkJoinPool task queue which would be request 100.

Comment: With single thread, after you complete task 1, you'll start with task 2. You don't steal work from yourself. BTW, I would suggest you to start a discussion on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org - it's better suited for theoretical discussions, and some Kotlin authors also answer there often.